# FancyShowCaseView not showing in onCreate()

Tags: android, oncreate, showcaseview

I want to show start case view in on create method:

```
new FancyShowCaseView.Builder(this)
            .title(getString(ShowCaseViewEnum.ADD_COURSE_START.messageId))
            .build()
            .show();
```

When I do this I can see case view screen but only for very short time and then  it 
disappears. I have tried to use some delay but it didn't change anything. 
When I run the same code in some on click method everything works right.
I'm using this android lib: https://github.com/faruktoptas/FancyShowCaseView.